# foreach in method to return value

Tags: scala, methods, foreach

```
def a: Int = {
  for(i <- Array(1,2,3,4,5)){
    if(i == 3)
      return i
  }
}
```

The above method will not compile, I get the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
       for(i <- Array(1,2,3,4,5)){
             ^
```

The expected behaviour is that the method returns 3. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `return` is not normally used in Scala, and mutable data structures like `Array` are usually avoided. The idiomatic equivalent of your method (including the default from drexin's answer) would be something like `def a = 1 to 5 find (_ == 3) getOrElse 0` (or alternatively `val a = 3` :) )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is because your lambda in the `foreach` does guarantee to return a value. If you provide a default return value it should work.

```
def a: Int = {
  for(i <- Array(1,2,3,4,5)){
    if(i == 3)
      return i
  }
  0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because there is no else or a default return value.

If a method has return type Int, than all paths in that method must return an Int. This is not the case in your implementation. For example, if in the Array there would not be the number 3, nothing would be returned, which means the return type would be Unit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use Return in #Scala . 
The return keyword is not “optional” or “inferred”; it changes the meaning of your program, and you should never use it.

https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html