# How to avoid return statement and escape from for loop?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've been told to avoid use of `return` in Scala, although I'm not sure why.

I've got the following code, and it doesn't seem to return the proper thing *unless* I put the `return` keyword in there. Why do I need to put `return`?

```
def nextParen(chars: List[Char]): List[Char] =
  for(i <- 0 to chars.size - 1) {
    if(chars(i) == '(' || chars(i) == ')') {
      return chars.slice(i, chars.size)  // return HERE!
    }
  }
  List.empty
}
```

Comment: BTW: That's a method, not a function.

Comment: Why down-voting? this is a question of scala newcomer who want to understand how to do stuff right.

Comment: Why to avoid use of return in Scala, answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761409/5827450

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument for avoiding `return` is that it leads to code that is less readable, and not refactor-safe. It's not an absolute rule, if you find an algorithm that's best expressed that way, but usually code can be made clearer by writing it as an expression.

This particular code looks to be equivalent to:

```
def nextParen(chars: List[Char]) =
  chars.dropWhile{c => c != '(' && c != ')'}
```

In general, try to focus on writing *expressions* rather than *procedures*; rather than telling the compiler what steps it should take, tell it what the value is. Even if you didn't know about `dropWhile`, you could write the loop as a fold (e.g. `foldLeft`) that says what to do at each element of the list, and then the case where the list is empty at the end would fall out naturally, rather than needing two different branches for where there is a match and where there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using `return` when it clearly expresses your intent in a good algorithm.  However, you should be cautious about using it because it isn't necessary, and most things you want to do already have decent implementations in the collections library.

So, for example, your code works but is `O(n^2)` in the size of the list because you're indexing into a linear data structure.  It's much better to use

```
chars.dropWhile(c => c != '(' && c != ')')
```

or if you don't know about that, any of a huge number of alternatives:

```
val i = chars.indexWhere(c => c == '(' || c == ')')
if (i < 0) chars take 0 else chars drop i

var found = false
chars.filter(c => found || { found = (c == '(' || c == ')'); found })
```

You can probably come up with half a dozen more without trying too hard.  (Fold with an indicator, for/yield with an if clause, span, etc.)

So the best reason to not use `return` is that you should know your library.  Usually you don't need it; it's better to use a stock method that computes what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `for` in the imperative sense above. You don't have to use a return if you use it in a more functional sense i.e., as a `for-yield` or `fold` or `takeWhile`.

I think one of the biggest thing to wrap your head around when you move from imperative to functional (side-effect free) is the notion that you can express your code a sequence of *expressions*, each of which evaluates to a *value*. For example, a `for-yield` expression evaluates to a `value`. So in an imperative world you are executing a sequence of statements that is changing the state (data structures, console etc) around you.

PS: I've used a lot of terms (e.g., side-effect, for-yield, value) that may sound unfamiliar to a new Scala programmer. But with more experience they will make more sense. I would highly recommend this book - [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)